# Is there a place where we can see PHP <=> C++ equilavent libraries/function for a php developer starting with C++?

Tags: php, c++

Is there a place where we can see PHP <=> C++ equilavent libraries/function for a php developer starting with C++?

As a PHP developer starting with C++, I often ask myself: what is the equivalent of such-and-such PHP function in C++?

The advantage of php, is that we have a very nice site which documents about everything we might want to use. All the commonly used PHP modules are all listed in one place (http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php).

One of the difficulties of starting with C++ is that we always have to search all over the web for one (often one of many) equivalent of a php function.

It'd be nice to have a place where there is a table with the equivalent C++ library (or header) for each PHP module or group of function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct mapping for all php functionality to C++.

The languages are just too different and are designed for completely different purposes.

All C++ standard libraries are documented here:

- http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl
- http://www.boost.org
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Here is a link to Stack overflow that provides a list of useful resources.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%2b%2b&sort=info